# Query for a list of IDs using Dynamic SOQL from JavaScript

Tags: dynamic-soql, list-button

I'm trying to update multiple records and then send email notification using custom list button.

For this I need to get few fields off the related list.

One option would be traverse thru the related list using getElements... function, but it might not have all the fields you need ([solution is already posted](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/5094/list-view-custom-button-to-collect-values-of-selected-records)).

An alternative would be a SOQL query with required fields and selected ids you get from checkboxes. A.i.:

```
var records = {!GETRECORDIDS($ObjectType.obj__c)}; 
var soqlQ="SELECT name FROM obj__c WHERE Id='"+records+"'"; 
var customObj = sforce.connection.query(soqlQ);
var soqlRes = customObj.getArray("records");
```

The problem here is that syntax is not supported by SOQL:

> INVALID_QUERY_FILTER_OPERATOR',
>   faultstring:'INVALID_QUERY_FILTER_OPERATOR: SELECT name FROM obj__c
>   WHERE Id='a0OaxxxxxxxxMRDy2,a0OaxxxxxxxxLfbwY'

Alternative would be to construct the SOQL query in a dynamic way:

```
SELECT name FROM obj__c WHERE id='a0OaxxxxxxxxMRDy2' or id='a0OaxxxxxxxxMRDy2'
```

The trouble I have is that I do not know how to do one in JavaScript.

Any help or alternative ideas are very appreciated. Thanks, ~dzh

**Edit: Solution is**

```
var records = {!GETRECORDIDS($ObjectType.obj__c)}.toString().replace(/,/g , "','"); 
var soqlQ="SELECT name FROM obj__c WHERE Id in ('"+records+"')";
```

Comment: Dzh- I have a request can you please add your edit as answer.. That is little bit misleading.. If you add as answer and mark as ans then other can find easily useful. Bythe way thanks your logic worked for me. :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you're dealing with a list of IDs, you want to use 'IN' instead of '='. The SOQL statement needs to end up looking like this

```
SELECT name FROM obj__c WHERE id IN ('a0OaxxxxxxxxMRDy2', 'a0OaxxxxxxxxMRDy2')
```

**Edit by OP**: it's been a while since I had the problem, but I've put this in my original post and as per Ratan's suggestion, I should mark this as accepted answer:

```
var records = {!GETRECORDIDS($ObjectType.obj__c)}.toString().replace(/,/g , "','"); 
var soqlQ="SELECT name FROM obj__c WHERE Id in ('"+records+"')";
```